# Copying models between workspaces

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am setting up deployment pipelines for our models and I wanted to support this scenario:

1. User registers model in `test` AML workspace in test subscription, checks in deployment code/configs that references the model version (there is a `requirements.txt`-like file that specifies the model ID - name and version)
2. Azure DevOps CI is triggered after code checkin to run `az ml model deploy` to a test environment.
3. User decides after that endpoint works well, wants to deploy to prod. In Azure DevOps, manually invokes a prod pipeline that will use the same checked-in code/configs (with the same referenced model):

   - copy the model from the `test` AML workspace to a new registered model in the `prod` AML workspace in a different subscription, *with the same version*
   - run `az ml model deploy` with different variables corresponding to the `prod` env, but using the same checked-in AML code/configs

I've looked at the MLOps references but can't seem to figure out how to support step 3 in the above scenario.

I thought I could do an `az ml model download` to download the model from the `test` env and register it in the `prod` env. The registration process automatically sets the version number so, e.g. the config that references `myModel:12` is no longer valid since in `prod` the ID is `myModel:1`

How can I copy the model from one workspace in one subscription to another and preserve the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use model tags to set up your own identifiers that are shared across workspace, and query models with specific tags:

```
az ml model update --add-tag
az ml model list --tag
```

Comment: Thanks - that's a good workaround. So I guess I would still have to download the model from one subscription and upload to another subscription? With this approach though I could ensure I'm referencing the right one with specific tags.

Comment: Did you figure out whether your download/upload approach worked?  I'm also wondering if that would be necessary if you weren't changing subscriptions.