# Copy pipeline from one ML Studio to another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am very new to Azure ML Studio. We have ML studio with 1 pipeline and 7 components. The requirement is to restore the contents from one subscription to another. I am familiar of restoring the ADF pipelines using ARM template. Is there any way to restore ML related pipeline and components?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying models between workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716459/copying-models-between-workspaces)

Comment: [Azure ML Studio Designer - Is it possible to copy pipeline or pipeline drafts from one workspace to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69859398/azure-ml-studio-designer-is-it-possible-to-copy-pipeline-or-pipeline-drafts-fr) and [Copying/Migrating AzureML Service Experimentst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994701/copying-migrating-azureml-service-experiments)

Answer (score 0):

The classic methodology to copy is ***clone*** which is no longer supported. The alternate and easy procedure is using ***YAML file***

The best way to clone or copy the pipeline from one subscription to another is using **YAML file**.

Steps to be followed:

For YAML pipelines, the process for cloning is to copy the YAML from the source pipeline and use it as the basis for the new pipeline.

1. Select the ***pipelines*** from the left panel

[image]

2. [Navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops#navigating-pipelines) to the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops) details for your pipeline, and choose Edit.
   [image]
3. Copy the pipeline YAML from the editor, and paste it into the YAML editor for your new pipeline
4. To customize your newly cloned pipeline, see [Customize your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops).